# Receiving FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/argument-error) while calling credentialWithLink in Angular Fire

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

I am trying to link an email address through email link verification to a Firebase account created using a Phone Number. I followed the docs and created the below function, but I am receiving `FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/argument-error)` error for the call to `EmailAuthProvider.credentialWithLink` function. I am providing the correct arguments as shown in [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/email-link-auth#web-modular-api_4). Can you guide me in the right direction to resolve this issue?

```
  import { linkWithCredential, EmailAuthProvider } from 'firebase/auth';

  linkEmailWithPhone(email: string): void {
  
    this.gms.authService.firebaseAuth.currentUser.then((user) => {
      linkWithCredential(
        user,
        EmailAuthProvider.credentialWithLink(
          email.toLowerCase(),
          window.location.href
        )
      )
        .then((usercred) => {
          console.log('Successfully linked email credential!', usercred.user);
          // The provider is now successfully linked.
          // The phone user can now sign in with their phone number or email.
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log('Error linking email credential', error);
          // Some error occurred.
        });
    });
  }
```